# Does local MongoDB Server has a rate limit?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB Atlas has rate limit of 100 requests per minute per project but if I host mongodb on my own server then will it have a rate limit or I can make unlimited read/write calls per minute to database. (obviously it is relative to the specifications of server) I am using Node js for making calls with mongoose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, when you install MongoDB in your own premises, then you don't have any limit. Of course, the system has some [MongoDB Limits and Thresholds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) but I don't think you will hit any of them.

Comment: How can we get around this, isn't ATLAS the premium Cloud as a Service MongoDB offering? We are shocked to encounter this today and spent a lot of time migrating over. Any suggestions outside self hosting?

Comment: @user3919920, I assume this limit apply for the Atlas free account. If you pay more, then I don't think you will have this limit.